# reload data in tableview in same screen

Tags: ios, uitableview

How can I reload data after delete contacts in favoriteTable cell (I delete contacts clicking on delete button in the cell when i am already in favoriteTab and i should reload the same screen i'm already watching)

favoritesTableViewController

```
//
//  favoritesTableViewController.m
//  MaverickApp
//
//  Created by Gregory Mezentsev on 12/30/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Alex&Gregory. All rights reserved.
//
#import "ModelUser.h"
#import "favoritesTableViewCell.h"
#import "screenController.h"
#import "favoritesTableViewController.h"
#import "userDetailsProfile.h"

@interface favoritesTableViewController (){
    NSArray* myFavListId;
    NSMutableArray* myFavListContactsData;
}

@end

@implementation favoritesTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.actualLoggedUser  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"2"];
    [self reloadData];
  }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)reloadData {

    NSLog(@"Favorites tab was loaded");

    //get id of my favorite contacts
    myFavListId = [[ModelUser instance] getUser:self.actualLoggedUser].contactsFavoriteList;

    //get data of my favorites contacts
    myFavListContactsData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i=0; i < [myFavListId count] ; i++) {
        User* us = [[ModelUser instance] getUser:([myFavListId objectAtIndex:i])];
        [myFavListContactsData addObject:us];
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return myFavListContactsData.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    favoritesTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"favoriteCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    User *us = [myFavListContactsData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.actualLoggedUser = self.actualLoggedUser;
    cell.contactUserId = us.userId;
    cell.contactName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",us.fname,us.lname];
    [cell.contactImage setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:us.imageName]];
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    User *us = [myFavListContactsData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UIStoryboard* sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    userDetailsProfile*  udVC = [sb
                                 instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"userDetailsProfile"];
    udVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    udVC.userDetailId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", us.userId];
    [self showViewController:udVC sender:self];

}

@end
```

favoritesTableViewCell

```
#import "favoritesTableViewCell.h"
#import "ModelUser.h"

    @implementation favoritesTableViewCell

    - (void)awakeFromNib {
        // Initialization code
    }

    - (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
        [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    - (IBAction)contactDelete:(id)sender{
        [[[ModelUser instance] getUser:self.actualLoggedUser] removeFavUser:self.contactUserId];
    }

    @end
```

Comment: Your table view controller should be listening for changes to the data model.

Answer (score 0):

You did not explain the problem, but it seems to me you should delete the deleted contact from `myFavListContactsData` array datasource, then you can reload.

A delegate would be appropriate for this situation.

You don't have to reload the tableView, once deleted from the datasource, you can remove the cell from the `tableView`:

```
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:
         [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

---

EDIT:

Your function would look like this:

```
- (IBAction)contactDelete:(id)sender{
    [[[ModelUser instance] getUser:self.actualLoggedUser] removeFavUser:self.contactUserId];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)sender.superview];

    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:
        [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
        withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

Comment: i have contacts in my favlist, i delete them from the model after i click the delete button on the row. i can see the change only when i go other tab and comeback (because it realod the data again from the model) . I want to see the change without going to the other tab and coming back @meda

Comment: @jdoe after you delete the contact, you should call the function to reload the data

Comment: delete from data source you mean delete from the Model class right? and then delete the row with your code? where i should paste it? @meda

Comment: I get this error in self.tableView: tableView not found on object of type 'favoritesTableViewCell *" The method delete is in the cell

Comment: You should move this code to the same file, do you really need `favoritesTableViewCell`

Comment: Use the same viewcontroller, for the button event you can add a method selector and get rid of your custom class

Comment: I used delegate. After click delete on cell, I perform reloadData method in tableView and update the screen!

Comment: How do it performer contactsDelete to data from table view (i don't have sender. I want to press delete button on cell and perform a method in tableview with delegate